# Trouble joining Windows Server 2008 to Domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

When I try to join my new server to my existing domain I get the following error:

"An attempt to resolve the DNS name of a DC in the domain being joined has failed.  Please verify this client is configured to reach a DNS server that can resove DNS names in the target domain."

I have tried all of the following already:

Successfully pinged the domain controller.
Ping the new server from the domain controller by IP address and by DNS name.
Ping the DC server from the new server by IP address and by DNS name.
Changed the network to DHCP (it was originally static).  No joy as static or DHCP.
Turned off all firewall settings.
Added the domain name to 'hosts' file.
Added the server name of the primary domain controller to the 'hosts' file in the new server.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance for any help!
Jim

Update:  With help from J. Brian Kelly (Thanks) I have managed to narrow down the problem to a DNS issue.  Specifically, UDP/53 packets are being sent (they are seen in Network Monitor), but are not getting to the DNS server.  But, I do not yet know why.

Update: The quested output from IPCONFIG for the HyperV host and the virtual machine.

**IPCONFIG from HyperV Server**

```
 Windows IP Configuration
 Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : HYPER
 Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : sfi-wfc.com
 Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
 IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
 WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
 DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : sfi-wfc.com

 Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 4:

 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
 Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Primary Network
 Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-30-48-CA-CC-7A
 DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
 Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
 Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::cd16:3ac2:3d4f:e275%679(Preferred)
 IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.1(Preferred)
 Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
 Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.10
 DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : -1476382648
 DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-12-10-20-E9-00-30-48-CA-CC-7A
 DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.5
 NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

 Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 3:

 Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : sfi
 Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82576 Gigabit Dual Port Network Connection #2
 Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-30-48-CA-CC-7B
 DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
 Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

**IPCONFIG from Virtual Machine**

```
 Windows IP Configuration
 Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DB
 Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
 Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
 IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
 WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
 DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : sfi

 Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : sfi
 Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual Machine Bus Network Adapter
 Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-66-03-02
 DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
 Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
 IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.128(Preferred)
 Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
 Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, August 29, 2009 10:44:45 AM
 Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, September 01, 2009 3:08:33 PM
 Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.10
 DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.5
 DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.102.5
 Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.5
 NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

 Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 8:

 Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : sfi
 Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.sfi
 Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
 DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
 Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

 Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

 Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
 Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 02-00-54-55-4E-01
 DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
 Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: Please post output of command "ipconfig /all" on DC and server.

Answer (score 1):

On Virtual Machine:

1. Change the network to static and type in these settings:

   **IPv4 - 192.168.100.128**

   **Subnet Mask - 255.255.255.0**

   **Default Gateway - 192.168.100.10**

   **Preferred DNS Server - 192.168.100.5**
2. In system properties, you must field the **Primary DNS suffix of this computer** with your domain name **sfi-wfc.com** and than tick the box **Change primary DNS suffix when domain membership changes**.
3. Restart Virtual Machine.
4. Use Fully Qualified Domain Name (**sfi-wfc.com**) instead of NetBIOS name when joining a domain.

Comment: I think this is right - the big issue is that your host and VM are pointed to different DNS servers - they should all point at the domain controller. Maybe you typo'd it but the VM's DNS is 102.5 instead of 100.5.

Answer (score 0):

Can you ping the domain name itself? For instance, if your DC is MyDC.MyDomain.net, can you ping MyDomain.net? Do you see any errors in the DC's or server's system event log corresponding to when you attempt to join the server to the domain?

Comment: I can ping the domain name and the DNS server by name if I have them in the hosts file.
When I remove the entries fro the host file I can ping the DNS server by name, but not the domain name.
When I do nslookup on the DNS server by name it timesout, but gives me the address.

Comment: Neglected to say.. there are no error messeges in the Domain Controller.

Comment: Remove all entries from the hosts file. Verify your DNS settings for the NIC. If all that is right, I would do a network trace on both your server and the DNS server to figure out why DNS resolution is failing.

Comment: Entries are removed from host file.  Removed them as soon as I proved it did not help.
I can ping and tracert from the new server to the DC and the reverse with no trouble.
Current configuration is DHCP and I verified that all settings and addresses are good.
By network trace do yuo mean get Wireshark and do a capture?

Comment: Possible relavent fact..  New server is running as virtual under Hyper-V.  I had no trouble joining the Hyper-V host machine to the domain.

Comment: Yup, or Network Monitor. It'll do, too, and doesn't require the WinPCap driver install. That way you can see if your server is sending outbound udp/53 to the DNS server, if the DNS server is receiving and responding, and if your server is receiving the response.

Comment: When I went to download Network Monitor I was unable to use IE because it appears DNS not working for IE either.  I did manage to get NM loaded however.  Have not figured out filters yet, so I am seeing a lot of noise.  However, I am seeing a serveral UDP/53 message and have not seen response.

Comment: Next steop, I am in stalling NM on DNS machine to see if requests are reaching there.  But why on earth would they not?

Comment: I am seeing the UDP/53 packets leaving the new server.  Not seeing them coming into the DNS server.  Cannot imagine what that might be other than something on the Hyper-V Server.  Maybe a firewall setting, but why on earth would it block DNS?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the new machine's virtual switch is properly set up.  If the firewall is off on all machines, (and it should be by this time) then the only thing left in the way (so to speak) is the vswitch.  the physical nic should have only the hyper v switch protocol enabled and the virtual port should not.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. To resolve I had to change Virtual Network connection of the Hyper-V to use a Legacy Network Adapter.

1. Shut down VM
2. Open Hyper-V manager
3. on the VM settings remove the Network Adapter.
4. Add a Legacy Network Adapter
5. Restart VM and retry.